# Sandbox Merchant ID Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I'm a newbie to learn about Paypal. There is an application that need to input merchant id or paypal email. When I use live account, I already know where I have to find merchant ID. But I didn't find merchant ID for sandbox, only API password and signature. Is there any way to create or find merchant id for sandbox? Or it's only for live account? Thanks before for any help or advice.

Comment: I really cannot see how this is too broad. He's asking where to find the merchant ID for a PayPal Sandbox account. I am having the exact same problem, I'm using an Extension for Magento, and this extension requires a merchant ID. I am easily able to find it on a standard PayPal account, but for some reason the merchant ID doesn't seem to be visible on the sandbox account profile. I can only see the API details.

Comment: I agree with @thephpdev on this one. This is a good question and it is focused on one small thing: location of the Merchant ID. If you use the PayPal's developer portal (2023), the Merchant ID can be found in Sandbox account info details.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry for my bad. I have found that merchant id. I have to login on this url first. https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/aboutBusiness

[image]

Comment: May I ask where exactly you found the Merchant ID? I am unable to find the Merchant ID for the Sandbox account I am signed in to.

Comment: Just click on the "Profile" link.

Comment: Look here https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings

Comment: In December 2016, you can find it in your Sandbox Test Accounts: click the Business account, hit Profile, then you'll find it under "Email ID". It looks like an email, unlike the live one. Hope it helps.

Comment: In 2018, merchant account ID is changed name to seller account ID, can be found at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings. Hope it help :)

Comment: check here https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/aboutBusiness